# Form Manipulation using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to do some arithmetic on values entered into a form using select option values. For some reason, I am getting undefined in the console instead of the result value.

```js
function sum() {
  const Start = Number(document.getElementById('Start1').value);
  const End = Number(document.getElementById('End1').value);
  const select = document.querySelector('select');
  const choice = select.value;
  let result;

  select.addEventListener('change', setValue);

  function setValue() {
    if (choice === 'AM->PM') {
      result = (12 - Start) + (End);
    }
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('txtresult').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <label for="Starting">Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="Date" name="Date"><br>
  <label for="Starting">Start Time:</label>
  <input type="text" id="Start1" placeholder="Start Time" name="Start_Time">
  <!--Input #1-->
  <br>

  <label for="End Time">End Time:</label>
  <input type="text" id="End1" placeholder="End Time" name="End_Time" onkeyup="sum()">
  <!--Input #2-->
  <select id="AM/PM">
    <option value="">--AM/PM--</option>
    <option value="AM">AM->AM</option>
    <option value="AM">AM->PM</option>
    <option value="AM">PM->AM</option>
    <option value="AM">PM->PM</option>

  </select><br>

  <label for="result">Hrs Worked:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtresult" placeholder="Result"></p><br>
</div>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your select values are all `AM`.

Comment: You shouldn't add an event listener inside `onkeyup`. Every time the user types a character, you're going to add another `change` listener.

Comment: You should get `select.value` inside the `setValue()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, you have all of the `<option>`s defined with `value="AM"` except for the first (for which the value is empty). Because of this, your `if` within `setValue`:

```
if (choice==='AM->PM' ){
    result =  (12-Start)+(End);
}
```

will never evaluate to `true` and will therefore never set `result` to a value; it will remain `undefined` because you initialize it with `let result;`.

I would also like to point out that you are declaring `const choice = select.value;` in the `sum` function, but are not changing its value within the callback on `change` of the `<select>`. In effect, the value of `choice` will always be whatever the selected value is when `sum` is executed, and will not change when `setValue` is executed upon the user changing the `select` box.

Try changing your `setValue` function to this:

```
function setValue(){
    choice = select.value;
    if (choice==='AM->PM' ){
            result =  (12-Start)+(End);
    }
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('txtresult').value = result;
}
```

and your HTML `option`s to this:

```
<option value="">--AM/PM--</option>
<option value="AM->AM">AM->AM</option>
<option value="AM->PM">AM->PM</option>
<option value="PM->AM">PM->AM</option>
<option value="PM->PM">PM->PM</option>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! 
One question though: Why didn't you add a let statement when setting choice to select.value at choice= select.value?

Comment: @mujtabasai Glad it helped! I didn't put `let choice = select.value;` because the variable `choice` is already declared above in the context of `function sum()`. I believe you *can* use `let choice` there, but that may break the shared context of `choice` between `function sum()` and `function setValue()`. Just a couple other things to note: the way you've declared `function setValue()` means is has no presence outside of the context of `function sum()`, and you should also check Barmar's comments on your question, they raise an excellent point about adding listeners inside `keyup` events.